# UPDATE multiple values in table t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have multiple columns where one of them has varchar values as follow.

```
1
2
4
02
05
6
03
06
123
32
87
```

I want to find any record that has values starting with 0 > remove that 0 (so 02 > 2) and update that field so there is no value starting with 0.

How can I go about doing that instead of manually updating each record that has 0 in the front? Is that even possible?

Thank you

Comment: Why is this column varchar at all? Why not simply converting the whole column to integer?

Comment: I am not really sure behind the reason for choosing varchar data type.  converting the whole column to int sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code removes the leading zeros by casting the value to an integer and back to a character string:

```
update t
    set col = cast(cast(col as int) as varchar(255))
    where t.col like '0%'
```

Comment: This column is right now varchar > I want to remove all the leading 0's and convert it to int. would disregarding outer case in your query do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
update yourtable
set col = substring(col, 2, len(col)-1)
where left(col, 1) = '0'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c023ad/1)

Answer (score 1):

Run this query until everything is filtered out I guess...

```
UPDATE Table SET Column=RIGHT(Column, LEN(Column)-1) WHERE Column LIKE '0%';
```

[Edit] Gordon's approach is probably better.